# Is BLE 4.1 backwards compatible to BLE 4.0 ? Can a phone with bluetooth 4.0 talk with a mote with BLE4.1?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, mobile

BLE 4.1 is out and it could be considered the biggest news for internet of thing developers. I want to know if my mote with BLE 4.1 can interact with iPhone 6 which has Bluetooth 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this answer from TI E2E forum.

As per the Bluetooth SPEC, mote with BLE 4.1 should be backward compatible with Bluetooth 4.0. But you should keep in mind that you will not be able to take advantage of BLE 4.1 features. Mote will be as good as an Bluetooth 4.0 device.

Again it also depends on whether the mote device wants to go ahead with a BLE Connection with an older device. Because even if the SPEC says that 4.1 device is backward compatible, it goes to the manufacturer to decide whether they want to go ahead with an backward device.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I didn't look carefully enough so here's my revised answer:

As you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_v4.0) BLE is a feature of BT 4.0. and higher so also included in BT 4.1.

So it should work assuming your Iphone supports BT 4.0 properly, but unfortunately you cannot be sure with Apple products.